# Unable to create a package version. Support do not help

Tags: managed-package

I'm looking for people who had a similar problem before.

It's our first time generating a package. When I try to do it, via:

`sfdx force:package:version:create --package "X" --installationkey onekey`

I got this message:

> Can’t create patch version. Log a case in the Salesforce Partner Community and request that patch versioning be enabled in the org where you created the namespace for this package.

Obviously, I tried that but after 9 days I still didn’t get an answer.

Any thoughts on this? Is there anything else I can do by myself?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of package version are you trying to create? What kind of package is this? What does your sfdx-project.json look like?

Comment: The message indicates that it tries to create a **patch** version of the package. Is this your intention? Check the version number in the project configuration file. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_patch_version.htm) does mention you need to raise a case to enable patch versioning.

Comment: Thanks for commenting guys. 
It's a managed package. I first create a package following the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_pkg_base.htm

Got a package Id.
And now, I'm trying to create a version, like here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_pkg_ver.htm

Maybe I have one wrong version number?

Comment: I changed to "versionNumber": "0.0.1", now I'm getting 
"VersionNumber must be in the format major.minor.patch.build but the value found is [0.0.1]."

Answer (score 1):

Following @sfdcfox and @Chun tips, I figured out a few things:

1. For some reason, the version number must start with >1;
2. The docs mention a pattern "major.minor.patch", but the CLI requires a "major.minor.patch.build" pattern;
3. If you use a versionNumber like "0.0.0.1" you got that message to raise a case, even if it's your first release;
4. I just changed the versionNumber field to "1.0.0.0" and I was able to create a version, finally.

Thanks.